# How to import a file from a dfferent folder?

Tags: python, python-import

I am going nuts.

This works, when the python module is in the same folder:

```
mpm = __import__("MyPrivateModule")
```

First trap: Case sensitive in file name => real???

But how do I write it, when `MyPrivateModule.py` is some where else like `modules\MyPrivateModule.py`
or like `C:\data\coding\modules\MyPrivateModule.py`

Is there really no one line solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

python looks for files in a script’s current directory only.
This possible path to look for file is done using `sys.path.insert(index, 'path/to/file')` method.

So by doing:

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(1, 'C:\data\coding\modules\MyPrivateModule.py')
print(sys.path)
```

Look that we are inserting at index 1.

On digging deeper into `sys.path`'s type, it belongs to class list! Makes sense, has List like methods.

Comment: Thanks! Please believe me, I searched for this before. If you know, i searched wrong, what search string should I used?

Comment: Just ask your question in the browser, try to put the key words that helps you to find your answer, and be patient by checking many platforms to find the good answer for you.
Check here to know more about [How To Use Google To Search](https://searchengineland.com/guide/how-to-use-google-to-search) .

Comment: Yes, when I know the answer, I see how to get it by google. But most of the answers where with linux pathes, and I am a microsoft kid. So your first answer was perfect for me!